# Database design for user daily food and workout table daily activity

Tags: database, database-design

I'm builing an app who manage foods and workout together. i'm not sure who to store user daily activity

Actually i have a table food :

`id
name
energy
proteins`

Table meals to store the meals made with some foods and store the total nutriments values :

`id
name
cat
total_enery
total_proteins`

Table meal_food to store the foods in the meal  :

`meal_id
food_id
nb_portion`

Table Workout :

`id
name
type`

Table Exercices :

`id
name
type
duration`

Table workout_exercice

`workout_id
exercice_id`

> Now my question is how could a design a table in order to store user
>   daily activity ? i need to store foods, meals, workout, exercice

I need for each day grab a food choose a portion or grab a meal already stored, a workout or an exercice.

I was strating doing something like this but i'm really really not sure here  :

Table user_daily_activity

`id
day
food_id
meal_id
food_id_portion
workout_id
exercice_id`

Is it a good idea to try to group or should  i need to separe things  ? should i create tables like this to get more control ?

```
user_daily_food
user_daily_meal 
user_daily_workout
user_daily_exercices
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- You can choose a specific portion for a food, or duration for an exercise, or choose one from an already pre-defined meal/workout routine.
- You are interested in preserving a snapshot of the day, and can alter predefined meals and workout routines as necessary.

Then the simplest way would be to choose from the predefined meals and workout routines and store the results in daily activity:

```
id
day
food_id
food_id_portion
exercise_id
duration
```

If predefined meals and/or workout routines cannot change and/or you need to tie back to the original meals/workout routines (even if they can change), then I think you were left with the above tables you mentioned.  You could store the results separately for simplicity/normalization, then union the results:

```
select food_id, food_id portion
from
(
select id, day, food_id, food_id_portion from user_daily_food 
union all
select id, day, food_id, nb_portion from user_daily_meal 
  inner join meals on user_daily_meal.mealid = meals.mealid
) A
```

I would go with whatever produces the least redundancy, but that depends on the needs for the particular app.